# How to do a PUT or PATCH request in R using httr

Tags: r, httr

So I've seen a few posts regarding GET and POST requests using httr, but I am trying to figure out how to update a value in my company's database, and am trying to figure out how to use these functions. In particular, I am struggling with how to format the body parameter. For example, a glance at my database:

```
library("httr")

# I can do a post request to grab data from the companys db (they told me to use POST instead of GET)
my_request <- httr::POST("https://mycompany.com/ourdb/data/userInfo/", 
         body = '{}',
         httr::add_headers(
           'X-login-Key' = '12345678',
           'OS-Version' = 'iOS 10.3.1',
           'User-Agent' = 'company/1.2.3.456',
           'Content-Type' = 'application/json',
           'X-Access-Token' = 'dkdfjueek12384kdndcos/da8L9u0=',
           'Nonce' = '1',
           'Accept' = 'application/json'),
          ), encode = "json")

http_status(my_request)$category
[1] "Success"

mycontent = content(my_request)
names(mycontent)
[1] "nonce"           "templateJson"    "settingsJson"    "plusButtonTree"  "templateVersion"

mycontent$settingsJson$user_gender
[1] 1
```

I would like to change the user_gender value in the database, from 1 to 2 (or any other number). I think I have to use the **body** parameter to do so, but I am not sure how to do this. Also I am not sure whether I should be using PUT or PATCH verb / function for this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late of a response to the original poster, but for future reference:

- The `httr` package has functions supporting both PUT and PATCH requests, which can be called with the same parameters as a POST request.
- For this particular example, one could replicate the same request, and just change the verb to PUT or PATCH:

```
    my_request <- httr::PUT("https://mycompany.com/ourdb/data/userInfo/", 
         body = '{"foo":"bar"}',
         httr::add_headers(
           'X-login-Key' = '12345678',
           'OS-Version' = 'iOS 10.3.1',
           'User-Agent' = 'company/1.2.3.456',
           'Content-Type' = 'application/json',
           'X-Access-Token' = 'dkdfjueek12384kdndcos/da8L9u0=',
           'Nonce' = '1',
           'Accept' = 'application/json'), encode = "json")
```

- The headers don't have to be altered, as they work the same way for PUT or PATCH as they do for POST.

Regarding the specifics of updating the information in the database referred to by the original poster, the way to actually update the value in the company database would have to be confirmed by the documentation of the API set up for this matter. There would have to be specific routes for a PUT or a PATCH request, built to update data, for those to work.

Else, the server interacting with the database would return a 404 status code, and the database would not be updated.